# How to pass email sent success message to view in codeigniter?

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, email

I'm using Codeigniter and its email and form validation libraries to create a contact form. After clicking the submit button I want to display something like "Thank you for your message" but whatever I try it doesn't work.

Here's my code:
Controller:

```
class contact extends MY_Controller {
function  __construct() {
    parent::MY_Controller();       

}

public function index(){        
    if(!isset($data['message'])){
        $data['message']="";   
    }     
    $this->load->view('contact', $data);
}   

public function send_mail(){
$this->load->library('form_validation');
         $this->form_validation->set_rules("full_name", "Name: ", "required|xss_clean");             
         $this->form_validation->set_rules("email", "Email: ", "required|valid_email|xss_clean");
         $this->form_validation->set_rules("message", "Message: ", "required|xss_clean");
         if($this->form_validation->run()==false){
             $this->load->view('contact');
         }
         else{             
         $this->load->library("email");
         $this->email->from(set_value("email"), set_value("full_name"));
         $this->email->to("my.emailaddress@mailserver.com");
         $this->email->subject("request from ...");
         $this->email->message(set_value("message"));
         $this->email->send();
         $data['message']="Thanks for your message!";
         $this->load->view('contact', $data);
         }

    }

}
```

The view:

```
$this->load->helper('form');
echo validation_errors();
echo form_open('contact/send_mail');
echo form_label('Name: ', 'full_name');
$data=array(
    "name"=>"full_name",
    "id"=>"full_name",
    "value"=>set_value("full_name")
);
echo form_input($data);
echo form_label('Email: ', 'email');
$data=array(
    "name"=>"email",
    "id"=>"email",
    "value"=>set_value("email")
);
echo form_input($data);
echo form_label('Message: ', 'message');
$data=array(
    "name"=>"message",
    "id"=>"message",
    "value"=>set_value("message")
);
echo form_textarea($data);
echo form_submit("contact_submit", "submit");
echo form_close();
```

Whenever I try to var_dump $data in the view it's not defined. So how to correctly reload the contact view and pass the "email sent" message to the view after submitting/sending the mail?

Answer (score 1):

```
//When you send $data from controller like
 $data['message']="Thanks for your message!"; 
 $this->load->view('contact', $data);

//You need to do below to get that values
  echo $message;
```

Comment: Thank you! That did the job! I'm not a big codeigniter expert but this is good to know! :)

Comment: @user2718671 it works but when form validation is `false` you will get undefined variable message in `view` file.

Comment: @karn thakkar you should turn off Error Notice in index.php like error_reporting(E_ALL^E_NOTICE); in switch case 'development'

Comment: @MayankTailor that will mute all notices during development which is not a good practice.you should cover all the **known** errors so that it should not be a reason for a `bug` in your app at later stages.

Comment: @karan that code will only turnoff notice, We will get all Warning errors and fatal errors and etc. here are all errors list of php http://www.careerride.com/PHP-types-errors.aspx. As a developer we should solve all errors generated by php but E_NOTICE is not required. :)

Comment: @MayankTailor i do consider notices too. may be I love debugging ;)

Comment: It only causes headche but as you wish dear:)

Answer (score 1):

you need to `echo $message` instead of `var_dump($data)`

so your controller becomes

```
public function send_mail(){
$data['message']="";
...
if($this->form_validation->run()==false){
         $this->load->view('contact',$data);
    }
else
{             
     $this->load->library("email");
     $this->email->from(set_value("email"), set_value("full_name"));
     $this->email->to("my.emailaddress@mailserver.com");
     $this->email->subject("request from ...");
     $this->email->message(set_value("message"));
     $this->email->send();
     $data['message']="Thanks for your message!";
     $this->load->view('contact', $data);
 }
```

and in view

```
echo validation_errors();
echo $message;
echo form_open('contact/send_mail');
```

Answer (score -1):

use session flashdata.

After

```
$this->email->send();
```

put this code

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('message','Thanks for your message!');
```

and following code in your contact view

```
echo @$this->session->flashdata('message');
```